# Event listener for the position of a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

How would I be able to call a method, according to the y coordinate of a UIImage view?
To be more specific, I have a dragable UIImageView. When the y co-ordinate of it is greater than a certain value, I want the colour of the screen to change.

code for dragging:

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

 if([touch view] == toggle)

 {



    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint newLocation = CGPointMake(toggle.center.x, location.y);

    toggle.center = newLocation;
    NSLog(@"%f \n",toggle.center.y);

}
```

}

Comment: you have to be more specific: when the coordinate becomes visible? was touched? has certain color?

Comment: BTW: I removed the tags for a reason — they are sense-less.

Comment: What do you mean by how do you drag it. I guess by touch and drag.

Comment: do you have some code for that?

Comment: My question has nothing to do with the dragging. All i want to know is how i can listen for changes of the y coordinate of a UIImageView and execute a method according to the change.

Comment: It has a lot to do with it: if you use GestureRecognizer the best solution is different than those if u use overriding the touches-methods in UIView or controller.

Comment: I a bit of a newbie at the moment. Could you give me an example? I will update my question with the code

Comment: I adapted your code. But actually I'd suggest to use [GestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW1). And have a look on the ["touches" sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007435), that also shows perfect dragging with GestureRecognizers.

Answer (score 0):

I could think of two ways of doing this. First is [Key-Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177-BCICJDHA) via the following:

```
[self.toggle addObserver: inspector
              forKeyPath: @"frame"
                 options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                 context: NULL];
```

I'm not sure if the `frame` property is Key-Value Coding compliant, though.

Or, and this is what I would recommend, you can:

(1) Create a [Prefix]ToggleViewLocationDelegate protocol, and add a locationDelegate property to your view/view controller, like so:

```
// YourViewOrViewControllerClass.h
// ...


@class YourViewOrViewControllerClass

@protocol [Prefix]ToggleViewLocationDelegate

- (void) toggleViewDidChangeFrame: (UIView*) toggleView;

@end

@class YourViewOrViewControllerClass

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<[Prefix]ToggleViewLocationDelegate> locationDelegate;
...

@end
```

(2) Make the class interested in the coordinate changes conform to the protocol, and
(3) In the `touchesMoved:withEvent:` method, inform the `locationDelegate`, like so:

```
- (void) touchesMoved: (NSSet*)   touches
            withEvent: (UIEvent*) event
{
  UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
  if (touch.view == toggle)
  {
    /* Fetch the new touch location */
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: self.view];

    /* Set the toggle's location */
    CGPoint newLocation = CGPointMake(toggle.center.x, location.y);
    toggle.center = newLocation;

    /* Inform the delegate when applicable */
    if (self.locationDelegate != nil)
    {
      [self.locationDelegate toggleViewDidChangeFrame: toggle];
    }
  }
}
```